# How to use github secrets as paths in github actions

Tags: yaml, github-actions, google-translation-api

I'm making up a github action that requires to use google-translation-api which has a `secrets.json` file required by the api.
I'm required to pass a path for the `secret.json` file in `project.yaml` such that

```yaml
- name: Compose
        env:
          GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }} # this should be the path to the secrets.json file
          GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID }}
```

here, I just copied the contents of secrets.json and put them as the values of `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in Github Actions Secrets. The error logs (Compose step):

```
0s
Run node index.js
  node index.js
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e ***0***
  env:
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ***
    GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID: ***
Error composing text: Error: The file at ***
  ***

Composed: null
  ***

*** does not exist, or it is not a file. ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/runner/work/Lime/Lime/***
  ***

  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEKAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCMb'
```

seem to be showing that the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` reads it as the path. I needed the secrets.json file to be confidential and not be exposed in the repository. How can I achieve it that the secrets read the contents as a .json file? or yet another workable way?

I'm using a javascript function
Heres the edited full code.

```
const { Translate } = require('@google-cloud/translate').v2;
const fs = require('fs');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

const translate = new Translate();

async function translateText(text, target) {
  try {
    const [translation] = await translate.translate(text, target);
    return translation;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error translating text: ${error}`);
    return null;
  }
}

const readmePath = 'README.md';
const readmeContent = fs.readFileSync(readmePath, 'utf8');

translateText(readmeContent,'sw' )
  .then((translation) => {
    console.log(`Translation: ${translation}`);

    const translatedReadmeContent = `${readmeContent}\n\nTranslated Text:\n\n${translation}`;
    fs.writeFileSync(readmePath, translatedReadmeContent);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
```

and use it in the yaml file

```yaml
name: Lime

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened]

jobs:
  translate:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2.4.1
        with:
          node-version: '14'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Translate README.md
        env:
          GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}
          GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID }}
        run: |
          node index.js
      - name: Commit and push changes
        uses: EndBug/add-and-commit@v7
        with:
          author_name: ${{ github.actor }}
          author_email: ${{ secrets.EMAIL }}
          message: 'Translated README.md to Swahili'
          add: 'README.md'
          push: 'true'
```

Comment: How is it being used? Include that part of your workflow in your question. Also, please retain its formatting while pasting in the question. Invalid formatting makes it an invalid GHA workflow. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using the google-translate api to make a github action on pull request that modifies the readme translates it to swahili then appends that text. now the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` field should have the path to the field. i later tried 
```
 echo "${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON }}" > secrets.json 
```
but on running `cat secrets.json` it doesn't copy it as a json object instead as plain text.

Comment: It's still unclear how you are invoking that API i.e. language and its usage. Please include that in your question.

Comment: Check edit. I've written the function in Javascript.
the .env contains 2 variables
```
GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID=project-id
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path/to/google_application_credentials.json
```

Comment: You can dump the JSON contents to a file and set the env var with its path.

Comment: Kindly share how i can achieve that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253447/discussion-between-clinton-njiru-and-azeem).

Comment: For example, you have `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON` secret, in a separate step, you can dump it in a file e.g. `echo '${{ GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON }}' > credentials.json` and then `set the env var like this `echo "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$PWD/credentials.json" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"`. That should do it. There are other similar threads on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the set secrets can't be read as json, so i just took the secret.json to a new private repository, then i placed its `raw.githubusercontent.com/Username/main/secret.json?token=***` url (the url had the token query too) in a secret variable called `GOOGLE_API_URL` then in my action i just created a steps to download and set the credentials like this:

```yaml
- name: Download credentials
        env:
          TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_API_URL }}
        run: |
          credentials=$(curl -s $TOKEN)
          echo "Downloaded credentials: $credentials"

      - name: Set credentials env var
        run: |  
          GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$credentials
          echo "Credentials env var: $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Google needs to document this better.

```js
const GOOGLE_TRANSLATE = new GoogleTranslate(
  {
    projectId: process.env.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
    credentials: {
      client_email: auth.client_email,
      private_key: auth.private_key,
    }
  },
)
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to the Settings tab of your GitHub repository.
2. Scroll to the GitHub Secrets section of the repo.
3. Add a new secret, providing an identifier and value for the GitHub secret token.
4. Reference the GitHub secret in code by prepending the text secret. to the identifier.

For example, if you have a secret named GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, you can reference it in your code as $ { { secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}. This should be the path to the secrets file.

You can also use environment variables in your workflows. To set an environment variable for a specific job or step, you can add an env key with a dictionary of key-value pairs.

```
name: My Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      MY_ENV_VAR: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}
    steps:
      - name: My Step
        run: echo $MY_ENV_VAR
```

This sets an environment variable named MY_ENV_VAR with the value of the secret named MY_SECRET.

Comment: This is exactly what i stated in my question as having tried. the ```${{secrets.MY_SECRET}}``` reads the contents inside and not that path. thats the problem.