# Github secrets not appearing in Environment Variables within Azure .net deployment

Tags: c#, .net, azure, github, deployment

I have setup continuous deployment of my .net 6 api  to Azure Web apps via a workflow on Github - for reference the base template is azure's "Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App" Extracts below. I have tried to implement env and my firebase credentials in many different ways within this file (on the job, build, deploy, steps etc) with no success. The environment secret is setup on the GitHub environment but it never pulls through to the environment variables in my deployment. I must be missing something and the use of the azure deployment pipeline makes it harder for me  follow and apply the solutions presented in the docs.

```
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - Dev
  workflow_dispatch:


jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    env:
        GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_CONFIG }}


    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
          include-prerelease: true

        ....

      - name: Env Build Step
        run: echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
        
  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Development'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          
      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2

        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access your Google Application Credentials by referring to this [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76158731/how-to-use-github-secrets-as-paths-in-github-actions) by Clinton nirju. Or directly echo the secret by referring to my workflow below which deploys .Net API into Azure Web App.

**My Github Action Workflow:-**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - webapp-apij

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          
      - name: Print Google Application Credentials
        run: echo ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}
      
      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'webapp-apij'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_4A9DDE8496AC4AD9AFBB31EC2E272AF0 }}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

You can also add your Google Application secret to your Azure Web app directly  by adding app-settings in your Deploy Azure Web app task like below:-

```yaml
- name: Deploy to Azure Web App
  id: deploy-to-webapp
  uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
  with:
    app-name: 'valleyapp-api'
    slot-name: 'Production'
    package: .
    publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_D9DE298E2BD642E3821D279D2C59C3F8 }}
    app-settings: '{"GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS": "${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}", "Setting1": "Value1", "Setting2": "Value2"}'
```

**My secret:-**

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Using secrets in GitHub Actions - GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions#using-secrets-in-a-workflow)